# ASP.NET application not working after being published - problems with Ajax pro tool kit

Tags: asp.net

After publishing the solution from Windows XP, the AJAX pro tool are not working after being deployed to Windows Server 2008.

How can I solve this problem?

Using C#, .NET 3.5, and DevExpress tools.

Comment: please post a screenshot or the text of the error you're seeing. Please clarify what Ajax toolkit you're talking about - who is the vendor?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess because you didn't post any error details but it is something to check.

Check and make sure the application pool for your webapp is set to run in .net 4.0 (you are using Server 2008 so I am assuming you are compiling for .net 4.0).  The default in IIS 7 is to start you off running in .net 2.0. Also make sure you are running in "Integrated" pipeline mode.